# android keep dialogbox open until user click on button

Tags: java, android

I have below code to display dialog box. Our requirement is user has too update app before login to the app.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginSlider.this)
    .setTitle("Update is Available!")
    .setMessage("Please update your app to use new features")
    .setPositiveButton("Update now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               final String appPackageName = getPackageName();
               startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
               }
            })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```

[image]

When I click out side of the dialog box. it gets disappear. I don't want that. How can I do this?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19064968/4771017) help? _"[...]to prevent dismiss dialog box on outside touch use this

 `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`"_

Though also check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526690/why-setcanceledontouchoutsidefalse-doesnt-work-in-alert-builder) for a case where it may not work as expected.

Comment: How can I use this in my code? I don't have dialog object

Comment: @Trobbins: when I tried to use both methods (setCancelable(false) and setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)). It's giving me error like: can not resolve method for one method

Comment: (for others:) My mistake, `.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean b)` is not a part of the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) API, however, `setCancelable(boolean b)` is

Comment: yeah.. What should I use instead of that method? I need to prevent outside touch as well.