# AlertDialog not dismissing when touch outside

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show an `AlertDialog` which could be dismissed with back button or touching outside the dialog. There are so many solutions over there and I know which the right one because I used it some time before. But now I can't achieve it. Here is my code:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog).create();
//Some setup of the dialog...
...
//This works when I press the back button
alertDialog.setCancelable(true); 
//This should be the right answer of my problem
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); 
alertDialog.show();
```

As I know, it's enough by calling this method with a true parameter value:

```
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

But won't work. Can someone enlighten me please!?

---

**Edit:** some testing

As [Ugas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7034513/ugas) mentioned, I changed the device for testing, and it worked.

- Android 5.1 (API 22): Not working
- Android 9 (API 28): Working as expected

Comment: can we please see your AppTheme_Dark_Dialog style

Comment: use this link  help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526778/7779712

Comment: I added the style but it's just some colors

Comment: That [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526778/7779712) prevent dialog from dismiss, I want to keep that behavior enabled.

Comment: Try adding `<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>` to your style

Comment: Didn't work :(!

Comment: I also tried setting some flags in the dialog window, and nothing changed.

Comment: I used `alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`so many time and always worked. I don't know if there's some new changes in newest Android versions or what.

Comment: @IgniteCoders keep calm and try to change the device that you are running the app

Comment: @Ugas do you know why this behavior changed from API 22 to API 28?

Comment: @IgniteCoders did you mean it works on api22 or 28

Comment: It works on API 28

Answer (score -2):

Remove

> alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

keep other code as it is and check.